# Is My Bootstrap Broken? Grid-System doesn't Work Properly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

My first question here and a very simple too.. So I got a little script here, which has to create rows with dynamic content. It will append 4 boxes (columns) in one row and then it will append the row to the container. If it is finished with that process it will append the container to the main container. Now i see that every column is at 100% width of the row on a 4K display like on a mobile.

This is what my script puts out:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="magazin-widget">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 2</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 3</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 5</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 6</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 7</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Dynamic Box 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't see the error in this markup... Maybe its my bootstrap? Because as far as I know it should look like this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

**Edit:**

Console is clean just logs:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
[cycle2] --c2 init--
```

Produced Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any css rule applied to `#magazin-widget`, such as `width` or something else?

Comment: update your post with screen shot of what you get and corresponding !console errors if any

Comment: I'll do but the div has no rules applied yet

Comment: Images shouldn't be used, but instead a snippet. I've added an edit for review to the post.

Comment: Okay, well now I've already uploaded an image also when its just simple text :S However everything is clean, could my Bootstrap have some problems/missing files whatever?

Comment: Don't have a 4K screen around, but testing your snippet in Chrome dev tools responsive mode doesn't show that behavior at any random simulated width between 1,000 and 6,000 pixels ... Are you sure you did not mess up any browser settings (zoom level, whatever) that might make this look weird _just for you_ ...?

Comment: @CBroe sooo is this snippet for you just as you expected? Well, if so or not, I'll check my settings thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Code works fine for me - what screen width are you looking at?

`col-md-xx` only effects viewports of 992px or wider - you may wish to use `col-sm-xx` or `col-xs-xx` for smaller devices.

see [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system#the-grid-sizes) for more info.

Comment: Hmm my viewport is 4K so I don't think this is the problem. Only thing I can imagine is that the container is less than 992 px wide but I'm using the default .container from bootstrap... I guess it could be a modified bootstrap, because there are other people working on there too, I'll ask around. For me It's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Do you have a somewhere I can see your code working so we can crack out the dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this work when I expand the snippet to full page view. Right now in the condensed view because bootstrap is responsive, everything is going to stack. I suggest you use something like `col-sm-3` to target a lower view port width.